# I get an unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str but I cannot figure it out. I read many questions but still cannot get it

Tags: python, string, arcpy

I am trying to build to a tool in ArcGIS that computs Landsat8 bands (b8-b4)/(b8+b4). I built the model in arcmap and then exported as a script. It runs a model but as a tool. I get an error in the last line where I compute the bands.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
band8_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if band8_input == '#' or not band8_input:
    band8_input = "band8_input" # provide a default value if unspecified

band4_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if band4_input == '#' or not band4_input:
    band4_input = "band4_input" # provide a default value if unspecified

RGB_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if RGB_input == '#' or not RGB_input:
    RGB_input = "RGB_input" # provide a default value if unspecified

clip_polygon = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
if clip_polygon == '#' or not clip_polygon:
    clip_polygon = "clip_polygon" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
RGB_clp = "C:\\egm722\\RGB_clp"
RGB_clp_prj = RGB_clp
b8_clp = "C:\\egm722\\b8_clp"
b8_clp_prj = b8_clp
b4_clp = "C:\\egm722\\b4_clp"
b4_clp_prj = b4_clp
NVDI = "C:\\egm722\\NVDI.img"
NVDI_prj = NVDI

# Process: Clip_RGB
arcpy.Clip_management(RGB_input, "321255.095287406 5732480.81845376 327031.683798733 5736711.6778568", RGB_clp, clip_polygon, "256", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")

# Process: Prj_RGB
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(RGB_clp, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")

# Process: Clip_b8
arcpy.Clip_management(band8_input, "321255.095287406 5732480.81845376 327031.683798733 5736711.6778568", b8_clp, clip_polygon, "-32768", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")

# Process: Prj_b8
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(b8_clp, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")

# Process: Clip_b4
arcpy.Clip_management(band4_input, "321255.095287406 5732480.81845376 327031.683798733 5736711.6778568", b4_clp, clip_polygon, "-32768", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")

# Process: Prj_b4
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(b4_clp, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")

# Process: Calc_NVDI
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("Float(\"%b8_clp_prj%\" - \"%b4_clp_prj%\") / (\"%b8_clp_prj%\" + \"%b4_clp_prj%\")", NVDI)

# Process: Prj_NVDI
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(NVDI, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
```

And I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\egm722\NVDI_arcpy.py", line 59, in <module>
    arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("Float(\"%b8_clp_prj%\" - \"%b4_clp_prj%\") / (\"%b8_clp_prj%\" + \"%b4_clp_prj%\")", NVDI)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).


Failed to execute (NVDI)
```

Thanks for the help. From what I read it seems to be an syntax error but I cannot figure it out. Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: `b8_clp_prj` and `b4_clp_prj` are strings. So, how are you trying to subtract them?

Answer (score 0):

```
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("Float(\"%b8_clp_prj%\" - \"%b4_clp_prj%\") / (\"%b8_clp_prj%\" + \"%b4_clp_prj%\")", NVDI)
```

includes the expression

```
Float(\"%b8_clp_prj%\" - \"%b4_clp_prj%\")
```

but both operands are strings

```
b8_clp = "C:\\egm722\\b8_clp"
b8_clp_prj = b8_clp
b4_clp = "C:\\egm722\\b4_clp"
b4_clp_prj = b4_clp
```

In Python, strings cannot be subtracted from one another, hence the error.

Comment: This explains the error message, but what is the correct syntax, i.e. the answer to the question asked?

Comment: @barny Explaining the error message is the best I can do, since I don't know arcpy.  Maybe explaining the error message is enough to point the OP in the right direction.